# html5: input type number (or text if not recognized) of the same length for all browsers

Tags: html, input, numbers

What is the best way to add some attributes to`<input type="number">` so the length of this element is the same for all the most popular browsers?

Actually, I used size="5" for `<input type="text" size="5">` but I'd better use type="number".

Does `<input type="number" size="5" min="1" max="10000" value="1000">` so I put size attribute as well look correct?

Any more possible improvements so all browsers have **the same width** of this element?

Also (if possible) I would make it for the nearest future so I shouldn't change it within a year or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best option is to set input's size using css:

```
input[type=number]{
    width: ...;
}
```

then you are sure that it will be the same in all browsers